# Calling azure machine learning service pipeline externally without python sdk

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-machine-learning-service

I have published a pipeline created inside azure machine learning service workspace, and i have its rest endpoint with me.
I also have Service principal Id and secrets which have contributor access over the workspace.
I am trying to invoke this pipeline thorough its rest endpoint from adf using the SPn id and secret.
But i am getting forbidden error, is there a guideline how to schive it without using python SDKs.

Comment: I think i am not getting the bearer token correctly.... I am using https://login.microsoftonline.com/<subscriptionId>/oauth2/token......and passing the clientId, client secret and grant_type=client_credentials.... Is there other way to get the bearer token here in amls?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try first with bearer token produced by CLI:
   az account get-access-token --subscription

Does it work?